# Firewall rules to allow Graph API calls

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, firewall

Could anyone please help me setup/configure firewall rules in Windows Server for Graph API calls to these URL's?

"https://graph.microsoft.com/*"

"https://login.microsoftonline.com/.onmicrosoft.com/*"

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for reaching out.

As the Graph API is a RESTful API using HTTPS calls, there will technically be a unique URL for each call. However, assuming you want to use v1.0 of the API, all URLs will start with "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/*".

You could whitelist "https://graph.microsoft.com/*" to allow for use of different versions of the API.

For authentication purposes, you will also need to allow calls to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.onmicrosoft.com/*"